# Adding definition to current selector of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to add a sound to every button sub-view in my UIView. I have so many of these buttons so I dont want to make a category or subclass of UIButton because in that case I have to change class name everywhere.

Is there anyway that I just loop [currentView subViews] and get button one by one, and add an action method.

Please keep in mind that buttons already have actions as well. So i am in search of some way to add definition to that action selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like below...its not tested but should work...

```
for(UIButton *button in currentView.subViews) {
    if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(playSound) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested and that worked for me. Thanks guys. Method first added as target will be called first in case of multiple actions.